# Knitting R codes as a word file

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

I really would like to knit my R codes in a Word file, and I have knitted codes a few hours ago; however, it suddenly don't work. :(

I looked up some answers in this site, and tried some solutions, but it didn't work.

First, I restored Rcpp, but it didn't change anything.
Second, I used rs.restartR, but it also didn't work.
Third, I tried to find a solution at https://yihui.name/knitr/options, but I still don't have an idea. ;-(

My error messages on R Markdown are shown as below.

```
processing file: my_data.rmd
(*) NOTE: I saw chunk options "1st paragraph, eval=FALSE"
please go to https://yihui.name/knitr/options
(it is likely that you forgot to quote "character" options)
Error in parse(text = cpde. keep.source = FALSE) :
  <text>:1:14: unpredictable symbol
1. alist('
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_params -> withCallingHandlers -> eval -> parse_only -> parse
```

What happens to my R studio? (T_T)
Dose anyone who can solve my problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should give a reproducible example, i.e. the source code of your `my_data.rmd` file.

I guess you should use `"1st paragraph"` rather than `"1st paragraph"`.

That is to say,

````
```{r some.option=1st paragraph, eval=FALSE}
#some r code here
```
````

should be

````
```{r some.option="1st-paragraph", eval=FALSE}
#some r code here
```
````

Comment: I do apologize for not adding my R codes, and I appreciate for your comment. Finally, R markdown works!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Never mind. It's my honor that my solution helped you.